# PHP preg_replace turning $ to the letter S

Tags: php, seo, preg-replace

I currently have a really great `preg_replace` system going on for my seo needs, but I'm having trouble with one character specifically and that's the $. The code I have returns the $ as a blank but I would prefer it if it turned the $ to the letter S. It's probably just a minor tweak but I'm sure how to single it out.

```
    $urlname = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $info['name']);
    $urlname = strtolower(trim($urlname, '-'));
    $urlname = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $urlname);  
    $seourl = strtolower($urlname);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use, `strtr`

```
echo strtr('Hello. I have $ Please replace the $', '$', 'S');
```

**See Demo [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd65b9d3b50b5f85c59233f043641cd4657e2663)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("$","s","Hello $!");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it. I should have changed it before I stripped out all the other special characters. Thanks, Siddhu Siddhartha Roy.

```
    $urlname = str_replace("$","s", $info['name']);
    $urlname = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $urlname);
    $urlname = strtolower(trim($urlname, '-'));
    $urlname = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $urlname);  
    $seourl = strtolower($urlname);
```